# Is there any way for calling databricks widget output from one notebook and use that as an input in another notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, widget, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a use case where my first notebook is taking values from synapse pipeline as a widget.I want to pass the output of this widget as an input to the dataframe which is present in my second  notebook.

**FIRST NOTEBOOK**

```
dbutils.widgets.text("input", "","")   //Input coming from synapse pipeline
"input": dbutils.widgets.get("input")
input = "/mnt/" + dbutils.widgets.get("input")
print(input)
```

**SECOND NOTEBOOK**

I want to use the input from first notebook to the second notebbok as show below.

```
% run FIRST NOTEBOOK
df = spark.read.csv(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be done differently - your first notebook need to run second notebook, not vice versa...  Because the first notebook is the entry point when is called from the Synapse.

In your case, you can pass parameter to `%run` using the `$variable` syntax, and then pull that data using another widget (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#use-databricks-widgets-with-run)).

So first notebook will look as following (in `$input=$input`, first `$input` is the name of variable, and second - refer to your `input` widget):

```py
dbutils.widgets.text("input", "","")   //Input coming from synapse pipeline
"input": dbutils.widgets.get("input")
input = "/mnt/" + dbutils.widgets.get("input")
print(input)
%run ./FirstNotebook $input=$input
```

And the second notebook

```py
input = "/mnt/" + dbutils.widgets.get("input")
df = spark.read.csv(input)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to run my first notebook inside my second so that i can use the input from first to second. That is because my first and the second notebook is not linked anywhere and my synapse pipeline is also independent I cannot use the output of first notebook activity as the input parameter.